# Wordpress: Display all posts that are tied to a custom taxonomy i created...

Tags: wordpress

I need to display all the categories I created for a custom post type then inside of each category I need to loop all the posts that are tied to that category.

I tried constructing my WP_Query a number of different ways and I can't get it to work at all.

Here's the code I have now:

```
$categories = get_categories('taxonomy=faqcat&order=DESC');
foreach ($categories as $cat) {

    // loop through all  posts tied to category here
}
```

Updated Code.. still doesn't work.. keeps displaying the same posts in each category.

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories('taxonomy=faqcat&order=DESC');
foreach ($categories as $cat) :

    echo '<h1>' . $cat->name . ' (' . $cat->cat_ID . ' )</h1>';
    $q = new WP_Query(array('cat_ID' => $cat->cat_ID, 'post_type' => 'faq', 'tax_query' => array('taxonomy' => 'faqcat')));
    if ($q->have_posts()) : while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
      echo $post->ID;      

    ?>
            <pre> <B><?php the_title(); ?></b></pre>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
            <br/>
        <?php endwhile;
    else:
        ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    <?php
    endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/59425

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fix:

```
    <!--faq page -->
    <div class="faq">
        <?php get_template_part('./template/global/breadcrumbs'); ?>
        <h3><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></h3>
        <?php
        $categories = get_categories('taxonomy=faqcat&order=DESC');
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            $i = 0;
            ?>
            <div class="faq-title">
                <h2><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2>
            </div>
            <?php
            $answers = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'faq', 'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'faqcat', 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => $cat->term_id,),),));
            if ($answers->have_posts()) : while ($answers->have_posts()) : $answers->the_post();
                    $i++;
                    ?>
                    <div class="faq-post" id="faq-<?php echo $i; ?>"> <span class="close-tab"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                        <div class="faq-post-detail">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>  
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                endwhile;
            else:
                ?>
                <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
            <?php endif;
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: This code snippet just worked perferctly for me! Thx for sharing this.